# Is it safe to register with CancellationToken.None?

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

Why is the following even legal?

```
CancellationToken.None.Register(delegate { });
```

Why does, for example, [`Register`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635.aspx) not throw an exception here? Is it because the above amounts to a [NOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)?

**Background:** The reason for asking this question is to understand whether a method accepting a `CancellationToken` needs to be coded defensively against `CancellationToken.None` when registration is involved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[CancellationToken.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.none.aspx) is not a null reference, but rather an empty cancellation token.  As such, it does have an instance.  The registration will never fire, as the source will never register as being cancelled, but it will go through "properly."

I would still put a check and code defensively against this, however, unless you are careful about Disposing the [CancellationTokenRegistration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokenregistration.aspx) returned properly.

---

Edit:

Upon further investigation, if you register against `CancellationToken.None`, you will effectively be doing nothing, and the `CancellationTokenRegistration` returned will not require disposal.  This will not keep a reference to your object or delegate, and not form a leak, so it is a no-op for practical purposes.  This should be safe to do, and should not require defensive practices to avoid on your end.

Comment: I realize that CancellationToken is a value type and therefore always has a value with CancellationToken.None being equivalent to one that is default-constructed. Do you believe, however, the registration is a NOP by itself for empty tokens and therefore requires no defense?

Comment: @Atif: I just went through and checked what actually happens - it's safe, and requires no defense.  (I edited my answer to show)  There's a check in the Register method that just returns a new registration, and completely ignores the delegate if the token can't be cancelled, which is the case with CT.None.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't find that check you mention :), thus my question.

Comment: @Atif: Look for the CanBeCanceled check - if it can't be canceled, it just instantly returns a new registration object.